# Executing the same security keychain command with the same user yields different result through SSH vs GitHub Action on MacOS runner

Tags: bash, macos, unix, command-line, github-actions

I am trying to move my existing workflow from GitHub's MacOS runner to my self hosted one. In the workflow one of the step involves using a command to set the default keychain to a temporary one created earlier, specifically:

```
security default-keychain -s {my_keychain_path}
```

This runs fine in GitHub's runner but I got the following error when the command is executed in my self hosted runner:

```
Will not set default: UID=501 does not own directory /Library/Preferences
security: SecKeychainSetDefault: Write permissions error.
```

I think this is probably due to the directory `/Library/Preferences`'s ownership belongs to the user group `wheel`, while the user used to execute the command in my self hosted runner does not belong to the `wheel` group.

However, when I try to SSH into my self hosted runner as the same user being used to run the workflow, and execute the exact same command, it does not yield the error and I can set the default keychain successfully.

What would be the reason that causes this difference?

Comment: Maybe related to [this recent post](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/)?

Comment: Thanks @VonC, but according to the post the changes was made on March 24, but I already encountered the issue way before that date...

Comment: Can you compare the result of `env` when logged manually through SSH as the same user being used to run the workflow, and the same `env` when executed by your self-hosted runner?

Comment: I compared the `env` in both cases, apart from the GitHub related ones when executed by the runner, some notable differences are the `SHLVL` is 4 in the runner case, while it is 1 through SSH, and there are the `SUDO_USER` and `SUDO_COMMAND` being set when executed by the runner. But as I am not executing the command with sudo in both case I guess it should be irrelevant?

Comment: So in both case, the $USER is the same? What about `id -a` (to check the primary and secondary groups)?

Comment: Yes, and the outputs from `id -a` are identical as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252898/discussion-between-vonc-and-peakcubic).